# Forgetting "The website is insecure" previous actions

Tags: selenium, https

Using Selenium with Chrome automating opening a web site I get the message "The web site is not secure.  ... go back or advanced".  This is what I want because I have to test for insecure sites.

The first time I ran this (I always try manually first) I got that message, clicked Advanced and then Proceed.  The problem is, subsequent times that I open the site it remembers my previous action and does not give me the warning.  Our Chrome starts each time with a clean cache so I don't think the cache is the problem.  Is there a way, via Selenium, that I can have it forget that I did a proceed in a previous test?

Answer (score 0):

Those are basically SSL certificates, you can handle that during driver initialization :-

**Code  :**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
```

Comment: I will try that, cruisepandey

Comment: Sure, let me know if you face any issues

Comment: It occurs to me I don't have control over initial driver setup. Can I update the driver later?

Comment: Yes why not, but it will open browser again